# Can I uniquely identify 2 check boxes so that I can add a different image to each?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox

Currently I am using an image for checked and unchecked checkboxes the html and css is below.

```
<div class="text-field-box text-field-box-mobile radio-button-box small">

                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkOffer1"  text="  "  runat="server" class="checkbox checkbox-mobile radio"   Visible="true" EnableViewState="true"></asp:CheckBox>
                <% Response.Write(Session("Offer1"))%>
                </div>
```

and css

```
                input[type=checkbox] {
                        display:none;
                }
                 input[type=checkbox] + label
                {
                    background-image: url("checkbox-default.png");
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    height: 25px;
                    width: 25px;

                    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
                    padding-left:30px;
                }

                input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
                {
                    background-image: url("checkbox-checked.png");
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    height: 25px;
                    width: 25px;

                    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
                    padding-left:30px;
                }
```

What I would like to do is find a way I can uniquely identify each checkbox so that I can have two checkbox fields with two different images.

These are my failed attempts I tried adding a extra class called `radio` 
like this. `input.radio[type=checkbox]` 
I also tried adding the `radio` class to the label like this `input[type=checkbox] + label.radio`

And tried the same with the ID's and I failed each time. Does anyone have a solution to my issue?

Comment: What did you try with the IDs? I mean, that is the way to go, so I wonder where it failed. Note: ID values may differ in the resulting HTML from the original ASP.NET source.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `input.radio[type=checkbox]` with `#ChkOffer1`?

Comment: I tried `#ChkOffer1 input[type=checkbox]` and `#ChkOffer1 input.radio[type=checkbox]`

Comment: I know there has to be some stupid thing I am over looking this monday morning.

Comment: `#ChkOffer1` is the ID of the radio button, so you don't have to (in fact, you can't) write `#ChkOffer1 input` to identify the button. Just `#ChkOffer1` for the button and `#ChkOffer1 + label` for the label. However, like I said, the ID value in the ASP source is not always the same as the ID value in the output. Check your generated HTML.

Comment: @MrLister I looked up the generated ID and they are the same, thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @jaunt I wish it were that easy but when you use images you need to create a label in place of the checkbox, to my knowledge this is the only way I can do it in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I meant:

(Oh and, forgive the images please :) )

```css
#field1,#field2{
  display:none;
}

#field1 + label {
  padding:40px;
  padding-left:100px;
  background:url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/M/F/B/9/z/O/nxt-checkbox-unchecked-md.png) no-repeat left center;
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}

#field1:checked + label {  
  background:url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/2/v/i/n/T/tick-check-box-md.png) no-repeat left center;
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}

#field2 + label {
  padding:40px;
  padding-left:100px;
  background:url(http://www.adventureswithwords.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/unhappy_face_sticker-p217427116611791537qjcl_400-390x390.jpg) no-repeat left center;
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}

#field2:checked + label {  
  background:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXWLioYfp2eZyyJ2g2VQM2YJd_PwFxrB-DDbZx1WwM8wXo20STCcDung) no-repeat left center;
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="field1"/>
<label for="field1">Label</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="field2"/>
<label for="field2">Label</label>
```

Comment: Not only did you answer my question, you gave me a better way of using images for checkbox fields, thank you!